How to fix error in Postman's get new access token?
Configurations:
Auth type: Oauth 2.0
Client Id: provided
Client Secret: provided
grant_type: client_credentials

I am trying to retrieve an access token in Postman by clicking "Get New Access Token" button, but it is throwing an error in the console saying only:
Error: []

It throws error even though the request is successful (as seen in the console). The request body contains the following:
{"tokenData":{"access_token":"access-token-here","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31556926},"errors":[],"success":true}

My assumption is that postman is expecting this kind of format by default:
{"access_token":"access-token-here","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":31556926}


The Postman Authorization helper is expecting those keys in a flat object.
This aligns with the OAuth 2.0 standard.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.1

The parameters are included in the entity-body of the HTTP response
using the "application/json" media type as defined by [RFC4627].  The
parameters are serialized into a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
structure by adding each parameter at the highest structure level.
Parameter names and string values are included as JSON strings.
Numerical values are included as JSON numbers.  The order of
parameters does not matter and can vary.

You could setup a pre-request script to work with non-standard responses.
The following is an example of authenticating to Microsoft that you can use as a base line.
let moment = require('moment');
let currentDateTime = moment(new Date()).format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");
let tokenExpiry = moment(pm.environment.get("bearerTokenExpiresOn")).format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss");

// console.log("currentDateTime: " + currentDateTime);
// console.log("tokenExpiry: " + tokenExpiry);
// console.log(pm.environment.get("bearerToken"));


if (!pm.environment.get("bearerToken") || currentDateTime > tokenExpiry) {
    pm.test("Pre-request check for Environment Variables", function () {
        let vars = ['client_id', 'scope', 'tenant_id', 'client_secret', 'scope'];
        vars.forEach(function (item) {
            // console.log(item);
            pm.expect(pm.environment.get(item), item + " variable not set").to.not.be.undefined;
            pm.expect(pm.environment.get(item), item + " variable not set").to.not.be.empty;
        });
        pm.sendRequest({
            url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + pm.environment.get("tenant_id") + '/oauth2/v2.0/token',
            method: 'POST',
            header: 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            body: {
                mode: 'urlencoded',
                urlencoded: [
                    { key: "client_id", value: pm.environment.get("client_id"), disabled: false },
                    { key: "scope", value: pm.environment.get("scope"), disabled: false },
                    { key: "client_secret", value: pm.environment.get("client_secret"), disabled: false },
                    { key: "grant_type", value: "client_credentials", disabled: false },
                ]
            }
        }, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                pm.test("Pre-request Microsoft login Status code is 200", () => {
                    pm.expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    let resJson = res.json();
                    // console.log(resJson);
                    let token = resJson.access_token;
                    // console.log(token);

                    function parseJwt(token) {
                        var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
                        var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
                        var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
                            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
                        }).join(''));

                        return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
                    }

                    let decoded = parseJwt(token);
                    // console.log(decoded);
                    let expiryDate = new Date(decoded.exp * 1000);
                    // console.log(expiryDate);

                    pm.environment.set("bearerToken", token);
                    pm.environment.set("bearerTokenExpiresOn", expiryDate);
                    // console.log("bearerTokenExpiresOn: " + pm.environment.get("bearerTokenExpiresOn"));
                });
            }
        });
    });
};

This example is parsing the token as the API is question did not return an expiry date.
The code only gets a new token if the existing one has expired.  Pay  close attention to the data formats, as not all API's use the same format.  (Even the Microsoft API returns different formats based on what service is being authenticated).
Last thing to check is whether the authentication API has any options for controlling the output.  Sometimes you can send query parameters with the request to configure how the response looks which Postman supports in the advanced options within the Authorization helper.
